# How does angular remove whitespaces between <span>s?

Tags: html, css, angular

I must say that I never noticed this until last week. If you have the following HTML

```
<div>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>B</span>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tdrgLhx5/)

It is rendered as **A B**. However, if you render the exact same thing in Angular that space between A and B is removed. I've created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eiukwv?file=src/app/app.component.html) to demonstrate a couple of cases in Angular:

```
<h3>With normal space</h3>
<div>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
</div>
<br>
<h3>  With &amp;ngsp;</h3>
<div >
  <span>A</span>&ngsp;
  <span>B</span>
</div>
<br>
<h3>With ngPreserveWhitespaces</h3>
<div ngPreserveWhitespaces>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eiukwv?file=src/app/app.component.html)

I've tried to inspect the HTML with Chrome DevTools but I still don't understand how its done.For all cases the HTML/CSS is identical. Anyway, it's probably very simple. Any suggestions?

Comment: anything that's not text in between tags are removed, so basically everything is placed on one line

Comment: angular is compressing your code (or may it's related to stackblitz)

Comment: Of course, and in DevTools you don't see any of that, It all makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

By default display property of span is inline-block. This will create extra space between the span elements so we need to remove that by giving `font-size: 0` to the parent element. And you have to give font-size to your child elements. Like here i have applied `font-size:0;` to parent element i.e div and applied `font-size:1rem;` to children span elements of div.

```css
div{
  font-size: 0;
}
div>span{
  font-size:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <span>A</span>
 <span>B</span>
</div>

<span id="total">X</span>
<span id="max">Y</span>
```

Comment: Thats indeed a trick to fix that, but that was not my question :)

Comment: so whats your actual question. Could you explain me again?

Comment: In short, the question is: How does angular remove that white space, but the answer is already given by @Poul Kruijt